# Which database for dealing with very large result-sets?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mongodb, scalability

I am currently working on a PHP application (pre-release).

**Background**

We have the a table in our MySQL database which is expected to grow extremely large - it would not be unusual for a single user to own 250,000 rows in this table. Each row in the table is given an amount and a date, among other things.

Furthermore, this particular table is read from (and written to) very frequently - on the majority of pages. Given that each row has a date, I'm using `GROUP BY date` to minimise the size of the result-set given by MySQL - rows contained in the same year can now be seen as just one total.

However, a typical page will still have a result-set between 1000-3000 results. There are also places where many `SUM()`'s are performed, totalling many tens - if not hundreds - of thousands of rows.

**Trying MySQL**

On a usual page, MySQL was usually taking around around 600-900ms. Using `LIMIT` and offsets weren't helping performance and the data has been heavily normalised, and so it doesn't seem like further normalisation would help.

To make matters worse, there are parts of the application which require the retrieval of 10,000-15,000 rows from the database. The results are then used in a calculation by PHP and formatted accordingly. Given this, the performance of MySQL wasn't acceptable.

**Trying MongoDB**

I have converted the table to MongoDB, and it's speed is faster - it usually takes around 250ms to retrieve 2,000 documents. However, the `$group` command in the aggregation pipeline - needed to aggregate fields depending on the year they fall in - slows things down. Unfortunately, keeping a total and updating that whenever a document is removed/updated/inserted is also out of the question, because although we can use a yearly total for some parts of the app, in other parts the calculations require that each amount falls on a specific date.

I've also considered Redis, although I think the complexity of the data is beyond what Redis was designed for.

**The Final Straw**

On top of all of this, speed is important. So performance is up there it terms of priorities.

**Questions:**

1. What is the best way to store data which is frequently read/written and rapidly growing, with the knowledge that most queries will retrieve a very large result-set?
2. Is there another solution to the problem? I'm totally open to suggestions.

I'm a little stuck at the moment, I haven't been able to retrieve such a large result-set in an acceptable amount of time. It seems most datastores are great for small retrieval sizes - even on large amounts of data - but I haven't been able to find anything on retrieving large amounts of data from an even larger table/collection.

Comment: Did you consider giving a try to Elastica (https://elastic.co)? When it comes to aggregation/statistics it is really great. Usually it's a good idea to combine MongoDB for writing and keeping your Elastica index up to date in background.

Comment: There is no database and not a single software project out there that can do something different to what MySQL does, when you look at the core. In reality, every time MySQL is slow is because it's not configured. If you want performance, you need hardware resources - sufficient RAM, a good CPU and a fast SSD. If you don't have that, there is virtually nothing you can do in software terms to make something work fast on an outdated computer. Long story short - what's your MySQL configuration? You want everything to fit in memory so that all your aggregation is quick.

Comment: @iamtankist I haven't considered Elastica. There seems to be some issues people are having dealing with [this issue](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/ES-is-slow-when-I-try-to-return-a-huge-result-set-td4027757.html). I wonder if this is still the case? Have you used it yourself? N.B. My MySQL server sits on a vagrant box on my local machine, which deals very well with other situations. It doesn't strike me that the hardware is necessarily the bottleneck here, however, I could be wrong.

Comment: Hardware is always the bottleneck. This is why MySQL ships with default configuration so it can work on really, really old and slow devices. What is your MySQL configuration? What's the size of the data on the disk? Is the disk mechanical or an SSD? What storage engine are you using? Have you allocated sufficient RAM for aggregate operations that MySQL does? See all these questions? When DB is slow, it's almost always because it utilizes the disk to find data or to dump temporary data - and you have a slow disk.

Comment: @N.B. I see what you're saying. Being pre-production, the database is small - I try to keep the total rows on all the tables < 100,000 - usually about 90% of that is the table in question. The disk is SSD and relatively new. The database is InnoDB and the RAM allocated to the vagrant box is about 350MB, which seems sufficient when only doing GROUP BY on 50,000 rows - IE. memory has never been exhausted on these small(er) queries. I wonder if I increased capabilities of the machine - RAM, CPU etc. - whether I'd have a slightly faster query, but still be having the same problem?

Comment: What's the value for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`? Use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer%';`  to see what MySQL is working with. Default value is 8 MB, it should be set to a higher number.

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size = 134217728

Comment: There you go, InnoDB will use `134217728` bytes. That's meager 128 MB. I suggest booting up a VM with a few gigs of ram and let MySQL use 1 or 2 gigabytes for buffer_pool and measure performance after that.

Comment: Please show use *exactly* what you did. That would be: a) explain the use case you tested *properly* b) Describe the setup for *both* databases (schema/document structure, indices used, queries used and alike). c) Describe exactly what your your expected behavior is and how it differs from the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

I only read the first two lines but you are using aggregation (`GROUP BY`) and then expecting it to just do realtime?

I will say you are new to the internals of databases not to undermine you but to try and help you.

The group operator in both MySQL and MongoDB is in-memory. In other words it takes whatever data structure you povide, whether it be an index or a document (row) and it will go through each row/document taking the field and grouping it up.

This means that you can speed it up in both MySQL and MongoDB by making sure you are using an index for the grouping, but still this only goes so far, even with housing the index in your direct working set in MongoDB (memory).

In fact using `LIMIT` with a `OFFSET` as well is probably just slowing things down even further frankly. Since after writing out the set MySQL then needs to query again to get your answer.

Once done it will write out the result, MySQL will write it out to a result set (memory and IO being used here) and MongoDB will reply inline if you have not set `$out`, the maximum size of the inline output being 16MB (the maximum size of a document).

The final point to take away here is: **aggregation is horrible**

There is no silver bullet that will save you here, some databases will attempt to boast about their speed etc etc but fact is most big aggregators use something called "pre-aggregated reports". You can find a quick introduction within the MongoDB documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/

This means that you put the effort of aggregating and grouping onto some other process which could do it easily enough allowing your reading thread, the one that needs to be realtime to do it's thang in realtime.

Comment: Interesting. Pre-aggregated reports are a good solution to avoid a group in the aggregation pipeline, however, that's really only half my problem. Given that I'm dealing with 60-year-periods with a daily 'granularity', that's still over 20,000 days over 60 years - and given that this granularity can't increase beyond that, I'm back to my original question because it would seem I still need to fetch 20,000 rows. Correct me if I misinterpreted your answer. Appreciate the help! :)

Comment: @Luke if you really have no way around it you will just have to bite the bullet like Google Analytics and other Analytics programs do. They exist on realtime in very small groups, normally minute by minute but as soon as you request a report you have to wait for stuff to load. What pages are you making realtime exactly?

Comment: Most pages can be aggregated - whether it be by your suggested pre-aggregated reports or something else. The pages which require day-by-day control are reports of a kind, and will be viewed less frequently - but by no means infrequently. I'm worried about the scalability of having people wait. If each report takes upwards of 2-5s to load, I'm unsure as to where that leaves me with even a moderate amount of concurrent users.

Comment: @Luke personally I would try it, make sure to actually show a loading screen and not the browsers loading icon. My personal opinion is the problem would not be in concurrency it is just speed of what your trying to do. One thing is to also cache the response for like an hour or something so once it is crunched once then keep it for however long the data might be fresh still

Comment: Pre-aggregated reports or *eager aggregation* is the way to go!